# Three ways to configure OpenCV with Visual Studio?

Tags: opencv, cmake, nuget

I've been trying to configure OpenCV 2.4.6 C++ VS for many weeks with a pre-built library. I'm getting nowhere. It seems there are three ways:

1. Manually by changing the environmental variables.
2. Nuget. Apparently, out of my league.
3. Cmake, again out of my league.

I've been down many paths with the manual method. Tutorials, etc. They just don't cut it. Something is just different that stops me. For example, a moment ago, I noticed in the "close" list above, "OpenCV and VS config " looked hopeful. Someone there said to see his web site. It was in Spanish. Often the IDEs are just not the same.

Comments?

Comment: The link that I am including is for 64 bit windows. http://www.mkmoharana.com/2013/12/setting-opencv-in-visual-studio-2012.html

The file that he gives has properties for 32 bit too. Check it out.

Comment: Have you seen the CMake tutorials? It is one of the easiest ways to make sure your project has the right properties.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html).This gives a step by step configuration of opencv with visual studio.Or you can try [this](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/).

Comment: CMake sucks hard, but it was the only way i got it to work...

Answer (score -1):

Read [this page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html). This is a sample **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project (SO_example)

FIND_PACKAGE (OpenCV REQUIRED)

file (GLOB SOURCES "*.h" "*.cpp")

add_executable (so_example ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (so_example ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Put this along with your header and source files and then build your project files using the CMake GUI. That should do it.

HTH